# Bootstrap - How to use validation states on a <textarea>

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, textarea, styling

Bootstrap allows for validation states for input inside of forms, using
    `class="form-group has-error"`. But this doesn't work with `<textarea>`, and oddly enough neither does the `help-inline`, any help?

Edit:
This is the full input group :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="desc" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description:*</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <textarea autocomplete="off" class="form-control" rows="5" name="desc" id="desc"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add the class `form-control` to the `textarea` element.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/d5g1bcdp/)

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
    <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
```

The selector used for this is `.has-error .form-control`. Here is the default styling too:

```
.has-error .form-control {
    border-color: #a94442;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
}
```

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I have the form-control already applied to it, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @user3934360 Based on the HTML you just posted, it *should* work - http://jsfiddle.net/7p9bLfy0/ You have either changed the bootstrap styling or there is conflicting CSS involved.

Comment: Sorry about that it looks like what I have is a php problem, but thanks for helping!