# MVC validation of text area

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have the following partial code snippet that I use as part of validation in my Asp.Net MVC 5 app.

```
 public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        foreach (var note in Notes)
        {
            if (note.Notes.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("The note cannot be empty.", new[] { "Note" }); 
            }
        }
     }
```

The validation is successful in that if any note is null or empty, the validation message appears on the view, but the text area is not set with the class input-validation-error.

An example of the physical id is Notes_1__Notes with a name equal to Notes[1]Notes.

The field is defined within the viewModel as [Required]

Comment: You adding a error for a property named `Note` but that does not match `Notes[0].Notes`. But what is the purpose of this is you already have a the `[Required]` attribute, which will give both client and server side validation out of the box

Comment: It is not applying the highlight

Comment: I think it is a HTML/CSS issue. If you are using Bootstrap then it won't give default css for `<textarea>` see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26227498/1659563 may be it will help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using collection of Notes and applying validation-error on Note,you should apply validation-error on Notes[i].Note.